# Math.max() not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have this following function, where `Math.max()` is not working as expected. It is always alerting the 1st value from the arguments that are passing. Where is the mistake?

```js
function large(arr) {
   alert(Math.max(arr))
}

large(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)?

Comment: max doesn't accept an array as input. so Math.max(arraylist) will return NaN

Comment: You're not passing an array; you're passing five separate arguments and giving the name `arr` to the first argument. The other argument values are only accessible through the `arguments` keyword.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing multiple arguments, but your function only uses the first one.

In ES5 and before, you can use the [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method of a function  and the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

```js
function large() { 
   alert(Math.max.apply(Math, arguments)) 
} 

large(1,2,3,4,5);
```

In ES6 you can use the [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```js
function large(...arr) { 
   alert(Math.max(...arr)) 
} 

large(1,2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: @Mahi It allows you to call a function with an array (or array-like object) of arguments, with an unknown length.

Comment: Should probably specify that it's [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) in use, here.

Comment: @Walf Sure thing.

Comment: Note that you're using rest parameter syntax as well as the spread operator.

Comment: @nnnnnn Very true.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

If you want to use the [**arguments**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)  you can avoid the parameter of the function. Then use the `apply` function to call `Math.max`

```
function large() {
var _max = Math.max.apply(Math, arguments);
alert(_max)
};
large(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20,9000);
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/5tf0zh55/2/)